# C++: How to solve a char bug in a do while loop?

Tags: c++, string, debugging, char

Can you help me to solve this bug?
It is a game where you need to guess the hidden number. The problem is that when I enter a character that isn't an integer number, the program outputs a message infinitely,
[Here is bug message if i enter a char](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTo9O.png)
 but I would like to make this program to output only message "You haven't entered a number, please try again".
[Here is a normal execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68UTU.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
main(){
int a,b;
char c;
START:
    system("cls");
srand (time(NULL));
a = rand() % 100 + 1;
cout << "Guess The hidden Number Between 1 and 100" << endl;
do {
  cout << endl<<"  Enter Any Number : "; cin>>b;
  if(b>100||b<1) cout<<"     Try another number that is between 1 and 100!!!";
  else {
    if (b>a)
      cout <<"     =>Too Big";
    else if (b<a) 
      cout <<"     =>Too Small";
    else if (b==a) {
      cout<<"     =>You've Guess It!!!"<<endl;
      break;
    }
  }
}
while (b != a);
cout << endl << "Press 'q' to start. Press else to close ";
c = getch();
if (c=='q'||c=='Q') goto START;
}
```

Comment: And _the bug_ actually is? BTW, don't use `goto` please.

Comment: You need to check the input stream state for incorrect inputs. If no number was entered `std::cin` will refuse any further input until `clear()` is called and all the wrong input characters are consumed.

Comment: why not to use goto?

Comment: Because it stays in the way to write clearly structured code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `int b; cin >> b;` will try to read integer and will fail if where is no integer in the stream. Fail bit of `cin` will be set, you can check it either with `if(cin.fail()) {}` or just `if(cin) {}`. So, you need to extract junk input from `cin` before the next read. You can reach this effect by actually reading anything from `cin` and then trying to convert it to an integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int b;
    string s;
    do {
        cout << endl << "Enter Any Number: "; 
        getline(cin, s);
        try {
            b = stoi(s);
            cout << "Your code goes here." << endl;
        }
        catch (invalid_argument& ex) {}
        catch (out_of_range& ex) {}
    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: **error:**  _**`stoi`**_ was not declared in this scope,i've copied this code,but the error is the same,maybe it is because of the library?

Comment: @Alex `stoi` is declared in `<string>` since C++11. Did you include `<string>`?

Comment: maybe,i use code::blocks 17:12, i think the problem is the new version

Comment: @Alex, you can use [strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) if you don't have access to C++11. It will convert to `long` and return *0* in case if conversion isn't possible.

Comment: you should really upgrade to atleast c++11.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int b;
  char s[1];
  do {
    cout << endl << "Enter Any Number: ";
    gets(s);
    try {

        b = atoi(s);
        cout << "Your code goes here." << endl;
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& ex) {}
    catch (out_of_range& ex) {}
  } while (true);
}
```

Comment: `atoi()` doesn't throw these exceptions. It's inherited from the c standard library, and c doesn't have exceptions. Read more here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the stream breaking. When you do `std::cin << intNum;` with a non-integer input, the data types are non-compatible, so it doesn't know what to do. To "fix" the stream, you need to clear the stream of it's error state using `std::cin.clear()` then the standard practice is to ignore the rest of the line to avoid other invalid input. A code snippet would look something like this:

```
while(std::cin.fail())
{
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(1000000, '\n');
}
```

This will check if the stream is broken, clear the flag so it can take input again, then clear out the next 1000000 characters or to the next \n, whichever comes first.